# при загрузке файла из формы, он не отображается в $_FILES

Tags: php, html, form

Через html форму, мне нужно в php получить информацию о файле, который загружен из input file. Но в массиве $_FILES нет ничего.

Я делал на сайте загрузку аватара, абсолютно такую же, но там всё работало

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <div id="bookAvatarWrapper">
    <label id="forPreviewe" for="hide">Загрузить обложку</label>

    <!-- ДОБАВИТЬ ПРЕВЬЮ -->
    <input type="file" class="hide" id="hide" name="addPreview">
    <img src="images/leather_texture404.jpg" id="previeweImg">
  </div>
  <div id="bookAddWrapper">
    <!-- НАЗВАНИЕ -->
    <input name="nameBook" type="text" placeholder="Название книги" class="inputBook"><br><br>
    <!-- ОПИСАНИЕ -->
    <textarea name="descrBook" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Описание вашей книги"></textarea>

    <label id="addBookToForm" for="hide">Книга</label>
    <!-- КНИГА -->
    <input type="file" class="hide" id="hide" name="addBookToForm">
    <!-- ОК -->
    <input type="submit" value="Ок" id="addNewBook" class="inputBook" name="doneNewBook">
  </div>
</form>
```

вот php

```
 if(isset($_POST['doneNewBook'])){

    $bookPreview = $_FILES['addPreview'];
    $bookName = $_POST['nameBook'];
    $bookDescr = $_POST['descrBook'];

    var_dump($_FILES);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, проблема в том, что Вы не указали для формы enctype="multipart/form-data"